# enable copy paste option in window.showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

In my application some of the .aspx page are called by window.showModalDialog like below

```
window.showModalDialog('../SelectUser.aspx?',window,sFeatures);
```

where sFeatures is declared like below

```
sFeatures = "dialogWidth=400px;dialogHeight=450px;border=thick;center=yes;help=no;status=no;title=Task";
```

In all the page where the page is clled through ShowModalDialog, the copy paste option is by default disabled. How can i enable the copy paste option from showModalDialog page.

Answer (score 0):

`showModalDialog` doesn't allow you to copy and paste information between the window that opened the dialog with ShowModalDialog and the actual dialog itself. To do so, you'll need to open the page with `window.open` instead.

More information about this can be found both ["need help with ModalDialog"](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t164745-need-help-with-modaldialog.html) and ["showModalDialog"](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t88245-showmodaldialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

Quote from showModalDialog documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Neither modal nor modeless HTML dialog boxes support text selection or the standard shortcut menu for copy operations; however, you can imitate this functionality by using script with TextRange objects and event handlers for onmousedown and onmousemove, as in the following example.
>
> Code example: http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/showModalDialogLaunch.htm

As an alternative you can implement your own modal dialog

```
var dlg = window.open(url, '_blank', 'modal=yes,dialog=yes');

var winFocus = window.onfocus;

window.onfocus = function() {
    if (dlg /* && possible additional condition based on dialog flow */) {
        dlg.focus();
    } else {
        window.onfocus = winFocus;
        // callback for dialog closing
    }
}
```